# Python Flask Environment Variables File Error with my flask login system

Tags: python, windows, flask

I am new to running Python Flask on Windows. I'm used to Linux. My code works fine on Linux, with `source .env` but since I am on windows I made a env.bat and added set to each line like so:

```
set export SECRET_KEY=34uqhtg3rfhjqwief3woqijj4ki324jkDEWGF
set export DEBUG=True
set export APP_SETTINGS=config.DevelopmentConfig
set export DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///db.sqlite
set export FLASK_APP=src
set export FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

The error I am receiving when running manage.py:

```
File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Dash\manage.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src import app
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Dash\src\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    app.config.from_object(config("APP_SETTINGS"))
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\ws\Dash\env\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 248, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\ws\Dash\env\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 107, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\ws\Dash\env\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 92, in get
    raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: APP_SETTINGS not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
```

manage.py:

```
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup

from src import app

cli = FlaskGroup(app)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

**init**.py:

```
from decouple import config
from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config("APP_SETTINGS"))

bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

# Registering blueprints
from src.accounts.views import accounts_bp
from src.core.views import core_bp

app.register_blueprint(accounts_bp)
app.register_blueprint(core_bp)
```

config.py:

```
from decouple import config

DATABASE_URI = config("DATABASE_URL")
if DATABASE_URI.startswith("postgres://"):
    DATABASE_URI = DATABASE_URI.replace("postgres://", "postgresql://", 1)


class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = config("SECRET_KEY", default="guess-me")
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = DATABASE_URI
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS = 13
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
    DEBUG_TB_ENABLED = False
    DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS = False


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
    DEBUG_TB_ENABLED = True


class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///testdb.sqlite"
    BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS = 1
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False
    DEBUG_TB_ENABLED = False
```

What is the issue here? Thank you. Any help is much appreciated. I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not setting the environment variable correctly.

On Windows you simply use the `set` command, so in your `bat` file you should delete the `export` command as this is being interpreted as the string `"export"`.

See the [set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1) documentation here `set [<variable>=[<string>]]`